# Call history not showing when expanding the contact details

Tags: contacts, stock-android, 8.1-oreo, nexus-6p, call-history

I am using Nexus 6P with Android 8.1 Oreo. I am not able to see the call history under the contact details. It used to display the most recent call history when opening the individual contacts. Below is the screenshot that I used to see the contact's recent call history (highlighted with a green rectangle).

[image]

Assuming that I am not having a few permissions on the Contacts app but not sure what kind of permissions I should be granting.

So far, I have tried clearing the cache of the Phone app & Contacts app. Also ensuring that the Contact App & Phone App has storage access.

Comment: Seems to work for me, and I have Call Logs, and Storage granted permission along with the natural Contacts and Phone.

Comment: Grant `android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG` to Contacts app.

Comment: @IrfanLatif, My phone is not rooted. So, wondering is there any UI/steps to grant this permission!

Comment: @wbogacz thanks for your reply. So, any idea what must be causing in my case! thanks in advance

Comment: @IrfanLatif, I have Contacts, Phone & Storage as an option(s) under the App permission section. Wondering how do I get the READ_CALL_LOG permission into this list.

Comment: @IrfanLatif it's an Andriod's stock App and as I mentioned, I don't have this entire list of permissions. I just have Contacts, Phone & Storage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98557/discussion-between-shark-and-irfan-latif).

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar stock Android device with the Google Phone and Contacts app. And the call history under the contact has been missing since a long time now.
The only way to access the call history (for me) is to single tap on the contact name from the dialer/phone app and choosing *history*.

[image]

I know that's not your answer, but it is obvious that Google Contacts app does not have that implemented. You can probably choose a different Contacts app which has call log implemented under the contact details.

If it was working for you until recently, then uninstalling the updates for the app can help. You can do it in Settings > Apps. Probably an old version supported it and then Google decided to kill the nice functionality (as it always does).

Comment: Hmm, thanks for reply. Unfortunately, I don't even see the History as an option.I have Call, Tet, Set up & Pay as an options.

Comment: @SharK As I said, it is in the Google Phone (dialer app). It is not implemented in the contacts app.